# How do I track down ValidateAntiForgeryToken not supplied issue?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I was looking at our logs and came across an error:

> A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid.

It seems like one of the developers may have not added the token onto a page or did not send it via an AJAX call. The problem is I have no idea where in our code base this originated. It was logged by the [HandleError] logging code we added but we have no way of knowing which method caused this.

The stack trace only shows us the following which doesn't seem very helpful:

> at System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase
>   context, String salt)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName)

The OnException method in our BaseController looks as follows:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    Exception ex = filterContext.Exception;

    //
    // Custom logging code here was removed for brevity

    if (filterContext.Exception.Data.Contains("Description") == false)
        filterContext.Exception.Data.Add("Description", "Oops. Something went wrong!");

    //Displays a friendly error, doesn't require HandleError
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

    //Displays a friendly error, *requires* HandlError
    base.OnException(filterContext);
}
```

My question is:

**Is there a way to get the source of the exception, ie. to know what controller or source file threw the exception using ExceptionContext.**

Appreciate the help.

Comment: All the info you need should be available in the `filterContext` such as `Controller` and `RouteData`.

Comment: You sir, are absolutely correct. That was a rookie oversight on my part! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on BuildStarted's response, the answer lies in the RouteData property of filterContext. I have an object dumper that writes out the properties of any object and here is what I see in our logs now.

RouteData:

[0]: [controller, Assess]

[1]: [action, Setup]

[2]: [id, 2]

So now I know the exact method that caused this.